# How to add a page/post to the 'primary' nav menu?

Tags: theme-development, menus

In the wordpress, how can i add a page/post in the 'primary' nav menu ? By code ?
All i know from admin you can add it via appearance > menu.

Comment: What is wrong with adding the page/post via appearance > menu?

Comment: because developing theme, bruh @Florian